# interrupted lifeline in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am making a sequence diagram in Enterprise Architect. The situation I want to show is a process C that calls a number of parallel processes (D and D2) asynchronously. Each called process indicates by (aysnc) callback when they're done. The process that sent out the signals waits until all processes have sent their callbacks and only then will it reply to its client B.
I want to show that B is blocked until C replies. That works, but when I add the client of B, A to the picture, the lifeline for A shows an interruption.

In the diagram below, the calls from A to B and from B to C are configured as synchronous calls and the reply arrows are set as 'is return'. The calls from C to D and D2 and those from D and D2 to C are configured as asynchronous calls.

[image: Sequence Diagram as shown in Enterprise Architect]

Is it possible to show the lifeline for A as uninterrupted?
If so, how?

I am mostly puzzled by why it shows B's lifeline as uninterrupted, but not the one for A.

Comment: I think it heavily depend on your EA version. Please state.

Comment: @qwerty_so: it's version 13.5.1352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll state it for V13.5. Other versions might behave different.

Once you are at this point

[image]

right click the middle message to the left side

[image]

and tick Activation Down. That will yield:

[image]